# Automated collision detection and rectification for a force directed wordcloud in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, collision-detection, force-layout, word-cloud

I have been experimenting with creating a force directed layout using D3.js. In the following code, I populate a series of objects which are later rendered into text elements. I wish to avoid collision between the words, and adjust their representation on the grid accordingly.

I utilised the code written by Eric Dobbs here http://bl.ocks.org/dobbs/1d353282475013f5c156
but it is still not working for me. The objects end up flying all over the screen. I have spent many hours puzzling over this and I would greatly appreciate any help available.

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>  
<script>
    //arguments passed in when this class is modularised
    var metaDataObject = {"type":"wordcloud","label":"data1","data":"data2","color":"color"};

    var dataObject = {"data1":["apple","orange","pear","grapes","mango","papaya","kiwi","banana", "watermelon","strawberry","honeydew","dragonfruit","durian","pineapple","jackfruit","lychee","mangosteen","passionfruit","raspberry","blueberry","rockmelon","coconut","lemon","lime","pomelo","rambutan","aguave","longan","mandarin","calamansi","sugarcane","avocado","bittergourd","wintermelon","dates"],"data2":[100,50,150,40,70,60,30,35,95,120,60,70,80,15,30,140,100,170,200,40,90,20,180,99,66,55,130,20,50,55,100,120,30,20,90],"color":["#23af50"]};

    //transform raw data
    var frequency_list = transformData(metaDataObject, dataObject);
    frequency_list.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.size-a.size;
    });

    //set cloud container variables
    var cloudWidth = 600;
    var cloudHeight = 400; 
    var cloudContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", cloudWidth)
        .attr("height", cloudHeight);

    //set approximate scaling
    var largestQty = d3.max(dataObject[metaDataObject.data]);
    var rangeCap = cloudWidth*cloudHeight/7500;

    var scale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, largestQty])
        .range([5, rangeCap]);

    var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,10,15,20,30,largestQty])
    .range(["#ddd", "#ccc", "#bbb", "#aaa", "#999", "#888", "#777", "#666", "#555", "#444", "#333", "#222"]);

    var words = createText(frequency_list);

    var rendered = cloudContainer.selectAll("node")
        .data(words)
        .enter()
          .append("text")
            .attr("id", function(d, i) {
              return "t"+i;
            })
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.text;
            })
            .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
                return color(i);
            }) 
            .attr("font-size", function(d) { 
                return scale(d.size)+"px";
            })
            .on("mouseover", handleMouseOver)
            .on("mouseout", handleMouseOut);

    var force = d3.layout.force()
      .nodes(words)
      .size([cloudWidth, cloudHeight])
      .charge(-50)
      .gravity(0.1)
      .on("tick", tick)
      .start();

    rendered.call(force.drag);

    function tick(e) {

        var q = d3.geom.quadtree(words);
        for(var i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
            var word = words[i];
            q.visit(collide(word));
        }

        // console.log(d.x2);
        rendered
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });
    }

    function collide(node) {
      var nx1, nx2, ny1, ny2, padding;
      padding = 32;
      nx1 = node.x - padding;
      nx2 = node.x2 + padding;
      ny1 = node.y - padding;
      ny2 = node.y2 + padding;
      return function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
        var dx, dy;
        console.log(node.x2);
        if (quad.point && (quad.point !== node)) {
          if (overlap(node, quad.point)) {
            dx = Math.min(node.x2 - quad.point.x, quad.point.x2 - node.x) / 2;
            node.x -= dx;
            quad.point.x += dx;
            dy = Math.min(node.y2 - quad.point.y, quad.point.y2 - node.y) / 2;
            node.y -= dy;
            quad.point.y += dy;
          }
        }
        return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
      };
    };

    function overlap(a, b) {
        return !(a.x2 < b.x || 
                a.x > b.x2 || 
                a.y2 < b.y || 
                a.y > b.y2);
    }

    function createText(frequency_list) {
        var words = [];
        for(var wordIndex=0; wordIndex<frequency_list.length; wordIndex++) {
            var word = {
                x: Math.random() * (cloudHeight - 40) +20,
                y: Math.random() * (cloudWidth -40) +20,
                text: frequency_list[wordIndex].text,
                size: frequency_list[wordIndex].size,
                // x2: word.x + word.text.length * word.size /1.5,
                // y2: word.y + scale(word.size) * 1.1
            };
            word.x2 = word.x + word.text.length * word.size /1.5;
            word.y2 = word.y + scale(word.size) * 1.1;
            words.push(word);
        }
        return words;
    }

    function transformData(metaDataObject, dataObject) {
        //To transform data to this format:
        // var frequency_list = [{"text":"apple","size":100}, {"text":"orange","size":100}, {"text":"pear","size":25}, {"text":"grapes","size":301}, {"text":"mango","size":56}];
        var frequency_list = [];
        var wordFieldName = metaDataObject.label;
        var valuesFieldName = metaDataObject.data;
        var wordList = dataObject[wordFieldName];
        var valuesList = dataObject[valuesFieldName];
        for(var itemIndex=0; itemIndex<wordList.length; itemIndex++) {
            var item = {
                text: wordList[itemIndex].toUpperCase(),
                size: valuesList[itemIndex]
            }
            frequency_list.push(item);
        }
        return frequency_list;
    }

    function handleMouseOver(d, i) {
        d3.select(this).transition().attr({
            fill: "black",
            "font-size": scale(d.size) + 5 + "px"
        });
        cloudContainer.append("text").attr({
            id: "t" + d.text + "-" + d.size,
            x: 10,
            y:20
        })
        .text(function() {
            return ["weight: " + d.size];
            // return [""+occupiedSpaces[1].top];
        })
    }

    function handleMouseOut(d, i) {
        d3.select(this).transition().attr({
            fill: color(i),
            "font-size": scale(d.size) + "px"
        });
        d3.select("#t" + d.text + "-" + d.size).remove();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```